# Integration of GVIM with Firefox with Mozplugger

Tags: linux, firefox, gvim

I am wanting to make my Firefox browser open the GVIM application for codes and plain-text.

I added the following lines in mozpluggerrc:

```
text/x-c++src:c++: C++ File
text/x-c++src:C: C++ File
text/x-c++src:cpp: C++ File
text/x-c++src:cc: C++ File
text/plain:txt:Plain Text
: gvim $file
```

Nothing happens when I open C++ codes or (text/plain), also, text/plain is not listed on about:plugins.

Where is my mistake?